# Ajax loader for respective elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Actually i have trying to put an ajax loader in my application. I tried this

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
  }).ajaxStop(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
});
```

This is working fine. But the problem is whenever i click an element which starts an ajax request, the ajax loader(gif image) is displayed in a single place. But i dont want that i want the loader should be displayed respectively near each element which is clicked only near that element.

so i tried this,

```
$('.follow_count').live('click', function(){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
   $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
   }).ajaxStop(function(){ 
   $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
  });
});
```

where .follow_count (this is one of the ajaxelement) is a div element. Here i want when the .follow_count element is clicked the ajax loader should be displayed near that element.

Could any one help me out of this..

Comment: You have defined same id for all AJAX loading? It seems like so, it's NOT ok at all!!!

Comment: you should put your #ajaxBusy elem inside the div elem. Or you need to use absolute position to position #ajaxBusy elem inside the div elem.

Comment: No i did not give same id. i have given respective id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you change from `id` to `class` it will work:

```
$('.follow_count').live('click', function(){
  $(this).ajaxStart(function(){ 
   $(this).find('.ajaxbusy').show(); 
   }).ajaxStop(function(){ 
   $(this).find('.ajaxbusy').show(); 
  });
});
```

`ajaxBusy` must be a class not an `id` if you will repeat it!

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fdyya/) is a small example.

Comment: How it's not working? it should work, check example just for live click, it should work the same